# Understanding Scala's flatmap type conversions

Tags: scala, scala-collections

The docs for List state:

> The type of the resulting collection is guided by the static type of list. This might cause unexpected results sometimes. For example:
>
> // lettersOf will return a Seq[Char] of likely repeated letters, instead of a Set
> def lettersOf(words: Seq[String]) = words flatMap (word => word.toSet)
>
> // lettersOf will return a Set[Char], not a Seq
> def lettersOf(words: Seq[String]) = words.toSet flatMap (word => word.toSeq)

I'm having a hard time understanding this.  StringOps.toSet returns a Set of Char, so the first example ends up returning a Char Seq - fine.  That makes sense.  What I don't follow is why in the second example Scala constructs a Set instead of a Seq.

What exactly does "the resulting collection is guided by the static type of list" mean here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of [canBuildFrom](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/collection/Set.scala#L43) method defined in Set class. As you can see in the ScalaDoc's [CanBuildFrom](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom) trait it has thee type parameters `CanBuildFrom[-From, -Elem, +To]` where: 
**From** - the type of the underlying collection that requests a builder to be created. 
**Elem** - the element type of the collection to be created. 
**To** - the type of the collection to be created.

Basiclly when you calling your flatMap function on the set it implicitly calls `Set.canBuildFrom[Char]` which return a `Set[Char]`

As for the static type. When Scala is tring to convert between collection types it uses this `CanBuildFrom` trait, which depends on the static type of your collection.

**Updated for the comment**

If we add -Xprint:typer to the scala command, we can see how Scala compiler after the typer phase resolves implicit method Set.canBuildFrom[Char] which is used to in flatMap method

```
def lettersOf(words: Seq[String]): scala.collection.immutable.Set[Char] = words.toSet[String].flatMap[Char, scala.collection.immutable.Set[Char]](((word: String) => scala.this.Predef.augmentString(word).toSeq))(immutable.this.Set.canBuildFrom[Char])
```

Comment: Here's the thing - I totally missed the call to toSet in the second example!  That makes it all completely clear.  Doh.

Comment: @ScalaNewb I've updated the answer to show when Scala injects implicit method